# Firebase cloud firestore not working in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am building this app that makes use of cloud firestore. The problem is that firestore is not working. Here is what code I am using

Db.dart

```dart
class Db{

  // collection reference
  static final CollectionReference _collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collection("codes");

  static Future addOrUpdateCode(String code , double lat , double long) async {
    return await _collectionReference.document(code).setData({
      'lat':lat,
      'long':long
    });
  }

}
```

I have added this line in pubspec.yaml

```yaml
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
```

I am getting these errors

```
I/BiChannelGoogleApi(13145): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@b61eba8
W/Firestore(13145): (21.3.0) [FirestoreCallCredentials]: Failed to get token: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ yRequests to this API securetoken.googleapis.com method google.identity.securetoken.v1.SecureToken.GrantToken are blocked.�
W/Firestore(13145): #type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Helpq
W/Firestore(13145): o
W/Firestore(13145):  Google developer console API keyKhttps://console.developers.google.com/project/280924879656/apiui/credential ].
I/BiChannelGoogleApi(13145): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@b61eba8
W/Firestore(13145): (21.3.0) [FirestoreCallCredentials]: Failed to get token: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ yRequests to this API securetoken.googleapis.com method google.identity.securetoken.v1.SecureToken.GrantToken are blocked.�
W/Firestore(13145): #type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Helpq
W/Firestore(13145): o
W/Firestore(13145):  Google developer console API keyKhttps://console.developers.google.com/project/280924879656/apiui/credential ].
I/BiChannelGoogleApi(13145): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@b61eba8
```

The following APIs are enabled in the cloud console

[image]

Register through email/password also enabled in firebase

I am using these rules

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

I believe that is enough information. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore security rules are not properly configured. See [Get started with Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

Since you mentioned you are implementing Firebase Authentication, you're going to want something like the example they provide:

```
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

But note that you're probably also going to want to have multi-level administration which is done via *Custom Tokens*. See [Create Custom Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) and you'll probably end up with something like a rule allowing admin access to everything and then you'll narrow access from there, e.g.:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.admin == true;
    }
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It works. I also had to enable Token API in the cloud console.

Answer (score 3):

These rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

are denying read/write access to all users under any conditions. You have to change them to the following:

```
// Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions
// Warning: **NEVER** use this rule set in production; it allows
// anyone to overwrite your entire database.
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

or use `timestamp.date`:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 07, 28);
    }
  }
}
```

which will allow read and write until the specified time.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#allow-all